# Part of output panel should not be re rendered

Tags: visualforce

I have a form in my vf page which has many fields and a table. I have a sub div/output panel in the form. On click of a button I call an apex method and then rerender the form. I want the entire from to rerender apart from one sub div/output panel. Sample code:

```
<apex:form id="formId">
    //some fields
    <apex:outputPanel id="panelId">
         //some fields
    </apex:outputPanel> 
    <apex:commandButton action="{!callApex} rerender="formId" />
</apex:form>
```

Once the button is clicked I do not want the panel with id "panelId" to rerender. The panel has to be within the form and I cannot split the form. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put the bits you want to rerender into their own sections:

```
<apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:outputText id="section1">
      //some fields
    </apex:outputText>
    <apex:outputText id="section2">
      //some fields, no rerender
    </apex:outputText> 
    <apex:outputText id="section3">
      //some fields
    </apex:outputText> 
    <apex:commandButton action="{!callApex} rerender="section1,section3" />
</apex:form>
```